# Can I reverse the iPhone 4s scroll to top in Safari

Tags: ios, iphone

I just figured out the scroll to top thing on my iPhone which if you accidentally hit it in a long article makes your life rather miserable trying to find out where you were. Is there some way for me to undo it?

Answer (score 2):

This is baked into iOS and works in most iOS apps that have long text fields. There's no way to disable it.

Comment: FYI: It doesn't work in "most iOS apps." It's system wide. It'll bounce you to the top of anything that scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

This is a system-wide feature of scroll views. There is no system-wide undo. However, some applications [(such as Instapaper)](http://blog.instapaper.com/post/420370426) implement their own way of undoing it.